# Parsing Class writes last item twice

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, parsing, nsscanner

I am helpless. I parse this text...

```
<parse>HELLO</parse>
<parse>World</parse>
<parse>digit</parse>
<parse>wow</parse>
<parse>hellonewitem</parse>
<parse>lastitem</parse>
```

with an instance of NSScanner:

```
    -(NSMutableArray *)parseTest
{

    if (parserTest != NULL)
    {

        NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:parserTest];
        NSString *test;
        NSMutableArray *someArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        while ([scanner isAtEnd]!=YES)
        {

            [scanner scanUpToString:@"<parse>" intoString:nil];
            [scanner scanString:@"<parse>" intoString:nil];
            [scanner scanUpToString:@"</parse>" intoString:&test];
            [scanner scanString:@"</parse>" intoString:nil];


            [someArray addObject:test];

            NSLog(@"%@",test);


        }
        return someArray;
    }
```

Can't get my head around why I am getting the last object twice here in the returned array. What am I missing? Is there something wrong with the:

```
[scanner isAtEnd]!=Yes?
```

Thanks for any help!

Matthias

Comment: how do you know the array contains lastItem twice?

Comment: I tried your code, and it just worked for me without a single change.

Comment: by iterating trough it like this: 
`for (NSString *s in someArray) NSLog(@"%@",s);` This gives me out every item once just the last item ('lastitem') gets displayed twice in the debug console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the count of the someArray,

```
NSLog(@"%d",[someArray count]);
```

if it is 6, then you are doing something wrong in printing the values.

else if it is 7, then something going wrong somewhere, and need to be sorted

Hope the first condition is true.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Vimal!
Now this confuses me more and more. I found out that the error does not occur every time i run my program. Sometimes the array-count is 6 and everything is fine, sometimes it's 7 and `lastitem` gets displayed twice...

Comment: Need to apologize. I found out that the error occurs in the way i fetch the string which i parse. I mark your Answer as the correct answer as it brought me to this awareness.
I created a new Question to the topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257967/pipes-in-nsstring-fetched-by-nsmutableurlrequest Thanks anyone for helping!