# Pipes in NSString fetched by NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, pipe, nsmutableurlrequest

I have the following method to get the content of a file called parsertest.html from a webserver. However about one every 5 times i run my program, the fetched NSString contains a line of pipes at the end

> ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Here is my code:

```
-(NSString *)fetchTest
 {


NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebserver.com/parsertest.html"];


NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setValue:scraperUserAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];

NSString *dataInStringFormat = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];


NSLog(@"%@",dataInStringFormat);
return dataInStringFormat;

}
```

scraperUserAgent is set to `"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0"`

This is the content of parsertest.html

```
<parse>HELLO</parse>
<parse>World</parse>
<parse>digit</parse>
<parse>wow</parse>
<parse>hellonewitem</parse>
<parse>lastitem</parse>
```

this is the complete output of NSLog when the error occurs:

```
<parse>HELLO</parse>
<parse>World</parse>
<parse>digit</parse>
<parse>wow</parse>
<parse>hellonewitem</parse>
<parse>lastitem</parse>
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Thanks for any help!

Matthias

Comment: Could log the error parameter as well, there might be a problem reported at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringWithUTF8String` expects a NULL-terminated C string, but `[data bytes]` is not NULL-terminated. Use

```
NSString *dataInStringFormat = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

instead.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks a lot sir! Matthias